# Reordering vertices on a polyline (route)

Tags: arcgis-desktop, line, vertices, order

I have a route in which the second vertex is in the middle of the line. Route is about 130 miles long. This is preventing me from recalibrating.

Is there any tool that will re order or sort all the vertices in the line? Or maybe even reapply order in which they are drawn?

Answer (score 1):

ArcGIS has a "Points to Line" tool. The points need to be in the correct order (of the Point feature class) or you need an ID field to key on.

The easiest way to fix this might be to open the Sketch Properties and switch the coordinates of two vertices.